# The function $\exp: \mathfrak{su}(n)\to SU(n)$ is surjective

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras

**The function $\exp: \mathfrak{su}(n)\to SU(n)$ is surjective**

I am trying to prove this by induction and I have already showed for $n=1,2$. I have also proven that given $x\in SU(n)$, there is $y\in SU(n)$ such that $b=yxy^{-1}$ is a block matrix where each block is an element of $SU(1)$ or $SU(2)$, but I don't know how to use all this to prove that $\exp: \mathfrak{su}(n)\to SU(n)$ is surjective. Some help? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Note the exponential map $\exp:\mathfrak{g}\to G$ is $G$-equivariant, where $\mathfrak{g}$ has the adjoint representation; that is $\exp(gXg^{-1})=g\exp(X)g^{-1}$ for all $g\in G$ (assuming $G$ is a matrix Lie group).

Therefore, it suffices to show every diagonal element of $SU(n)$ is in the range of $\exp$. This should be pretty straightforward, since these all look like $\mathrm{diag}(e^{i\theta_1},\cdots,e^{i\theta_n})$ such that $\theta_1+\cdots+\theta_n=2\pi n$ (and you can show that $n=0$ without loss of generality here).

Comment: I cannot assume that  $G$ is a connected matrix Lie group, because for that I am just proving that $\exp: \mathfrak{su}(n)\to SU(n)$ is surjective, to conclude that $SU(n)$ is connected.

Comment: @user482152 (1) You did not specify that in the question. (2) I don't think $G$ connected is actually necessary, I was just adding in nice adjectives to be safe and not have to think while I was writing that sentence. (3) For $SU(2)$ specifically it is straightforward to verify conjugating an element of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ by an element of $SU(2)$ yields another element of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$. Can you do it?

Comment: Is every element in $SU(n)$ of the form $diag(e^{i\theta_1},...,e^{i\theta_n} )$ where $\theta_1+...+\theta_n=2\pi n$? 
Or are you using that every element in $x\in SU(n)$ is of the form $x=y^{-1}by$ where each block of $b$ is an element of $SU(1)$ or $SU(2)$?

Comment: @user482152 I am using the fact that every element of $SU(n)$ is conjugate to a diagonal matrix whose blocks are in $U(1)$. You and [this user](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3427975/for-all-x-in-sun-there-is-a-y-in-sun-such-that-b-yxy-1-is-a-matrix) seem to be working on the same problem. It is not true that every element of $SU(n)$ can be written with blocks from $SU(1)$ and $SU(2)$ - the author of that statement is probably mixing up $SU(n)$ with $SO(n)$ I think.

Comment: So is rhe function exp:()→()
is surjective? Could you illuminate also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4215267/955245? slightly different aspects

Comment: Is your idea based on the complete parametrization of maximal torus basically? (what else to add?)

Comment: @МаринаMarinaS Yes it is surjective. My idea is based on the fact all elements of a compact Lie group are contained in a maximal torus, and all maximal tori are conjugate (and the fact exp intertwines the adjoint actions). For nice compact groups like $SU(n)$, this fact relies only on the spectral theorem from linear algebra. In your question you seem to also care about using a basis for the Lie algebra (guessing you're coming at this from a physics angle).

Comment: thanks! +1 how about SO and Sp Lie groups? Are they also surjective?

Comment: how about exceptional Lie groups? Are they also surjective for exp maps? thanks

Comment: Like I said, the exponential map (from the Lie algebra to the Lie group) is surjective for any compact Lie group. It is not in general surjective for non-compact Lie groups.